# How to map through all inputs in a certain component in react

Tags: reactjs, api, methods

I want to be able to map through all components to so I can use the input data as a means of adding to by api query. I've been trying to ask similar questions with no results. Here is a method that I believe can be used. Do I need to add Inputs to the state somehow before I can map it?

```
handleInputChange = event => {
  const name = event.target.name;
  const value = event.target.value;
  const id = event.target.id;
  this.setState({
    [name]: value,
    [id]: ""
  });
};


handleFormSubmit = event => {
  this.loadContracts(this.state.search);
event.preventDefault();
var query = '';
('Input').map(function(){
  if (query != '')
  query += '&';
  query += 'filter=' + this.id + this.name;
})

search: function(query) {return axios.get("http://api/documents?" + query);
  }
```

In the handleInput Change I added a const id. Does that grab the id from me input?

then in handle form submit I'm trying map through the input to add to the empty query the data the user inputs.

the api should look like this after it is finished.

```
http://api/documents?filter=idxt001|1111&filter=idxt004|Pedestrian
```

Also, here is the input i want to map.

```
  <form className="form-inline ">

      {props.labels.map(label => (
      <div className="card border-0 mx-auto" style={styles} key={label.Id}>
        <ul className="list-inline ">
      <span>
        <li>
        <Labels  htmlFor={label.DisplayName} >{label.DisplayName}:</Labels>
        </li>
        <li >
          <Input  
            onChange={props.handleInputChange}
            value={props.search}
            name="search"
            type="text" 
            className={"form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2"} 
            id={label.DataField}
          />
        </li> 
      </span>
  </ul>
</div>
  ))}

 <div className=" col-sm-12">
  <button
    style={{ float: "left", marginBottom: 10, marginLeft: 36 }} 
    className="btn btn-success"
    type="submit"
    onClick={props.handleFormSubmit}
  >
    Search
  </button>
 </div>
</form>
```

**EDIT**
updated code to reflect @Tyro 's answer.

```
 class SearchPage extends React.Component {

state = {
  labels: [],
  results: [],
  contracts: [],
  search: "",
  formValues: {
    [DataField1]: value1,
    [DataField2]: value2,
    [DataField3]: value3
   }

};


componentDidMount(){
  this.loadLabels()

}

loadLabels = () => {
  API.getLabels()
    .then(res => {
      const labels = res.data;
      console.log(labels)
        this.setState({ labels })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

loadContracts = (query) => {
  API.search(query)
  .then(res => {
    const contracts = res.data;
    console.log(contracts)
    this.setState({ contracts })
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

handleInputChange(key, value) {
  const name = event.target.name;
  const value = event.target.value;
  this.setState({
    [name]: value,
  });
};


handleFormSubmit = event => {
  this.loadContracts(this.state.search);
event.preventDefault();
let query = '';
const formData = this.state.formValues
let keys = Object.keys(formData);
keys.forEach(k => {
  query += `${k}=${formData[k]}`
 })

};
```

And form..

```
const SearchForm = props => (

  <form className="form-inline ">

{props.labels.map(label => (
  <div className="card border-0 mx-auto" style={styles} key={label.Id}>
    <ul className="list-inline ">
       <span>
        <li>
          <Labels  htmlFor={label.DisplayName} >{label.DisplayName} : 
         </Labels>
        </li>
        <li >
          <Input  
          key={label.Id}
            onChange={(e) => {
              console.log(label.DataField, e.target.value);
              props.handleInputChange(label.DataField, e.target.value)}}
            value={props.search}
            name="search"
            type="text" 
            className={"form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2"} 
            id={label.DataField}
          />
        </li> 
      </span>
  </ul>
 </div>
))}

<div className=" col-sm-12">
 <button
    style={{ float: "left", marginBottom: 10, marginLeft: 36 }} 
    className="btn btn-success"
    type="submit"
    onClick={props.handleFormSubmit}
  >
    Search
  </button>


 </div>
 </form>
```

Current errors are with the formValues in the state

```
./src/components/Form.js
Line 18:  'DataField1' is not defined  no-undef
Line 18:  'value1' is not defined      no-undef
Line 19:  'DataField2' is not defined  no-undef
Line 19:  'value2' is not defined      no-undef
Line 20:  'DataField3' is not defined  no-undef
Line 20:  'value3' is not defined      no-undef
```

Comment: Where's your form? if you have the correct elements in your form you should be able to use serialise the data like this: `const formData = {}; e.target.value..map((value, index) => {
  formData[index] = value;
});`

Comment: @TyroHunter  I updated to show the form with input. Where would I insert the const formData? Do I remove all the code I added to handleFormSubmit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in the first place is you do not have the form input values in your state properly stored (and structured so you can easily loop against it), I'd suggest you set your state like so:

```
{
  formValues: {
   [DataField1]: value1,
   [DataField2]: value2,
   [DataField3]: value3
  }
}
```

1. Refactor your input change handler so it properly refers to the distinct field (using DataField if it's unique). Now you can store each input value with it's ID or key, I would suggest:

**EDIT**

```
<Input
   onChange={(e) => {
     /* log label.DataField and e.target.value,
        do you get the values?
        It should be the values we are interested in, and not 
        undefined, if it is look for the documentation of Input,
        especially on how to get the new values after onChange event */

     console.log(label.DataField, e.target.value);


     props.handleInputChange(label.DataField, e.target.value)
   }}
>
```

take note of the value of onChange, it's a function (to be invoked later, once the event onChange is triggered), and it's bound to it's corresponding input field ID

```
/* key and value corresponds to #1 label.DataField and e.target.value
so it should be defined. This is where you set the state */
```

2.) refactor `handleInputChange(key, value) {
...
}` so that it will store the desired values in your state

3.) Finally, iterate against it and feed to your api:

```
let query = '';
const formData = this.state.formValues
let keys = Object.keys(formData);
keys.forEach(k => {
  query += `${k}=${formData[k]}`
})
...
```

Comment: A couple questions. When I add forValue:{[dataField]: value1} to state, I get they are undefined. Are they supposed to be defined in the Input onChange event?  Second, if I refactor handleInputChange = event => to handleInputChange = (key, value) I can no longer use const name = event.target.name and const value = event.target.value. Finally, the last state goes in the handleFormSubmit correct?

Comment: You got the last 1 clear and correct. I edited the answer again, to make it clearer, I asked questions

Comment: Thanks for your help @Tyro. I was able to get the correct values in the console from the onchange function. But I must be missing something between the lines in my methods. I updated my question to show current. I'm getting a lot of undefined errors..

Comment: Hello @DenisJ I'm avoiding to baby sit you and trying to help you understand how to figure it out on your own. I see you have taken my suggestion on state.formValues literally, but that is just how I would want you to imagine your formValues data structure given three DataFields. So formValues should be initially empty = {}, and your handleInputChange should comply to the structure I suggested, so it should be like this:

`
const newFormValues = Object.assign({}, this.state.formValues, {[key]: value});
this.setState({
    formValues: newFormValues
  });
`

Comment: Point taken. I've been trying to hammer away at this for so long, I'm taking any advice very literally lol. But that got rid of my errors and makes sense seeing it written out. I'll try to finish it from here. thanks

Comment: No worries, but I don't wanna leave you in the air either.. so I'm glad you're making progress. I'm guessing you are at the final stage now? So just use #3 as a reference, because you actually have the right idea in that part. Now, trying to consume formValues how does your query string look like now?
`
keys.forEach(k => {
  query += `${k}=${formData[k]}`
 })
`; console.log(query)

Comment: yes very close. formValues is holding the state of the inputs. Made some slight changes to the query and am getting the correct query string format. Now just need to figure why it's not being appended to the api

Comment: ok well can't figure out how to append the query string to the api. It would make the most sense to be able to use this.loadContracts(query); in the handleFormSubmit since that is holding the correct string. and (this.state.FormValues) does get added to the api, but it appends an array with object object. This seems to be the closest. So does that mean that the value of query is being returned empty to the api?

Comment: you need to convert formValues to string, loop through it because it's an object. Which you can't append to your apiURL. In JS when you try to concat a string to an object, you usually get the [Object object] stuff, which means you did something wrong. I will be able to help if you can show the value of this.state.formValues, corresponding to your attempt to convert it to string. Which I also asked from my previous comment. `keys.forEach(k => { query += ${k}=${formData[k]} }); console.log(query)`

Comment: thats what I was thinking. Here's the query filter=IDXT001|1111&filter=IDXT002|4321

Comment: @Tryo I ended up adding query to the state and then just using this.loadContracts(this.state.query); to call the API. Weird thing is this only works after I click search once. Then it works fine each time, unless the page reloads.